# Customize ATT prompt on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, apptrackingtransparency

Is it possible to change the colour of the `Ask App Not to Track` and `Allow` button in the ATT prompt?

I've tried to update the tint colour of UIAlertViewController, which works for all other native alerts, but not for this one. Is it possible to customise it somehow?

```swift
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = UIColor.green
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions alerts are not customisable by the app.